# How to make sure that fragment is created in the activity from static method new Instance

Tags: java, android, android-fragments, software-design

I am designing a fragment to be used by other developers.
Fragments must have a public constructor that the android SDK use in creating fragments, but to pass data from the activity to fragment it's preferable to create a static method that creates the fragment in the Fragment class like this

```java
  public static FaceMatchingResultFragment newInstance(boolean matched, String param2) {
        FaceMatchingResultFragment fragment = new FaceMatchingResultFragment();
        Bundle args = new Bundle();
        args.putBoolean(ARG_PARAM1, matched);
        args.putString(ARG_PARAM2, param2);
        fragment.setArguments(args);
        return fragment;
    }
```

My question is there a way to make sure that the developer have to use this method and not the public constructor  ?

Comment: *is there a way to make sure that the developer have to use this method and not the public constructor ?*  - **no** ... edit ... you can assure in onCreate that fragment contains all needed arguments - in other case you can throw some meaningful exception

Comment: Make constructor priate.

Comment: @caisil he can't - Fragments are required to have a parameterless public constructor

Comment: @caisil the constructor must be public because the reflection call expects it to be.

Comment: override public constructor and have it throw an exception with a message that prompts developers to use the static one instead

Comment: @NikosHidalgo It will be thrown when system automatically recreates the Fragment

Comment: 1. Make contructor private. 2. Use this in SDK. ```Constructor<FaceMatchingResultFragment > declaredConstructor = FaceMatchingResultFragment.class.getDeclaredConstructor(null);
        declaredConstructor.setAccessible(true);
        FaceMatchingResultFragment frag = declaredConstructor.newInstance(null);
```.

Comment: @caisil where exactly should I add this code?

Comment: @Selvin I know but at least it will render the default constructor unusable, won't it?

Comment: again Android OS use public parameterless  constructor to recreate Fragment

Comment: @DavidIbrahim Use the snippet in SDK reflect, not in the static method.

Comment: @Selvin's answer is working with me, to throw an exception in the onCreate method.

Comment: @Selvin My bad, I just realised what you meant after looking at the static instance more carefully

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Checking if argument bundle is included during `onCreate` is the cleanest way to do it without messing around with reflection. If you want to show inline error when accessing no-arg constructor you can use `RestrictTo` annotation:

```
public class SimpleArgFragment extends Fragment {
    public static SimpleArgFragment newInstance(boolean val) {
        Bundle args = new Bundle();
        args.putBoolean("param", val);
        SimpleArgFragment f = new SimpleArgFragment();
        f.setArguments(args);
        return f;
    }

    @androidx.annotation.RestrictTo({RestrictTo.Scope.SUBCLASSES})
    public SimpleArgFragment() {
    }

    @Override
    public void onCreate(@Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

        if (getArguments() == null)
            throw new IllegalArgumentException("Missing arguments - use newInstance() to create.");
    }
}
```

Comment: upvote for this `RestrictTo`, it's very helpful thanks